# What is "philosophy" in Latin?

Tags: vocabulary, philosophy-terms

The Latin word I would use for to translate "philosophy" is *philosophia*.
But this is a transliteration of a Greek word.
Is there an originally Latin word for "philosophy"?
The closest word I could find is *sapientia*, but it doesn't seem to have the same nuance as *philosophia*.
Does *philosophia* have a closer Latin equivalent than *sapientia*?
I would assume the Romans had a word for their philosophical literature.

Comment: There is no "native" Latin word for philosophy for the same reason that there is no native English word for it: it was imported from the Greeks. At best, you can get a calque, but it would post-date *philosophia*.

Comment: @C.M.Weimer That would make a nice answer. "There is no good translation other than *philosophia*" is not what I expected, but it certainly won't make me object to it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Latin does indeed use the term [*philosophia, -ae*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dphilosophia), from the Greek [φιλοσοφία,](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0057%3Aentry%3Dfilosofi%2Fa).

Romans acknowledged that this was a Greek term:

> Ita fit ut mater omnium bonarum rerum  sapientia, **a quoius amore Graeco
>
>   uerbo philosophia nomen inuenit**, qua nihil a dis immortalibus uberius, nihil florentius, nihil praestabilius hominum uitae datum est. (Cicero, *De Legibus* 1.58)
>
> <sup>Thus it is that the mother of all good things is wisdom, **from whose love *philosophy* found its name in a Greek word**: nothing has been given to the life of men by the immortal gods that is more fertile, fruitful, and excellent.</sup>

Further evidence that a native term for this was never in widespread use comes from *De Officiis*. Given Cicero's proclivity for inventing Latin neologisms for Greek philosophical terms, it is significant that he views the *studium sapientiae* as a one-off translation while continuing to use *philosophia* afterwards:

> nec quicquam aliud est philosophia, si interpretari velis, praeter **studium sapientiae**. (Cicero, *De Officiis* 2.5)
>
> <sup>Philosophy, if you wish to translate the word, is nothing other than the **love of wisdom.**</sup>

Comment: Thanks! I guess I can parse that Cicero quote as an answer: "The translation would be *studium sapientiae*, but we use the Greek word *philosophia* in Latin."