# With which verb can I borrow from other languages?

Tags: vocabulary, word-request

If I want to describe that [the word *philosophia* was borrowed from Greek to Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4215/79), which Latin verb can I use for borrowing?
Verbs like *commodare* and *mutuari* sound a little weird for this kind of loan.
Should I go with a simple *sumere* or something else?

Comment: At first glance, mutuari/mutuare would seem to be correct. OLD gives as the definition 'To borrow (money, commodities). b (trans., e.g. words, ideas).' However, when I look at the 3 attestations that involve words (Cic. Orat. 211: 'aut novum facere verbum aut a simili mutuari'; Cic. Tusc. 2.43: 'a viris virtus nomen est mutuata'; and Quint. Inst. 10.1.13: 'ex proximo [i.e. a wd. cognate in meaning] mutuari'), all appear to be talking about 'deriving' words rather than 'borrowing' them in the sense that you're asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *Instutio oratoria* 1.4.7–8, Quintilian uses the verb *mutuor* to talk about how the letters Y and Z are 'borrowed' into the Latin alphabet to render some Greek words (text and translation from the Perseus website):

> an cuiuslibet auris est exigere litterarum sonos? non hercule magis quam nervorum. at grammatici saltem omnes in hanc descendent rerum tenuitatem, desintne aliquae nobis necessariae litterarum, non **cum Graeca scribimus (tum enim ab iisdem duas mutuamur)** sed propriae, in Latinis, ut in his *seruus* et *uulgus* Aeolicum digammon desideratur, et  medius est quidam V et I litterae sonus; non enim sic *optimum* dicimus ut *opimum*, et in *here* neque E plane neque I auditur.
>
> It is not every ear that can appreciate the correct sound of the different letters. It is fully as hard as to distinguish the different notes in music. But all teachers of literature will condescend to such minutiae: they will discuss for instance whether certain necessary letters are absent from the alphabet, not indeed **when we are writing Greek words (for then we borrow two letters from them)**, but in the case of genuine Latin words: for example in words such as *seruus* and *uulgus* we feel the lack of the Aeolic digamma; there is also a sound intermediate between *u* and *i*, for we do not pronounce *optimum* as we do *opimum*, while in *here* the sound is neither exactly *e* or *i*.

If *mutuor* can be used to talk about borrowing individual letters in order to transliterate a Greek word, perhaps it follows that an entire Greek word that has been thus transliterated can also be said to be borrowed.

(However, as I note in my comment to the original question, in most other passages where the verb *mutuor* is used in the context of words, it appears to describe the process of deriving brand-new words – or expanding the range of meanings of existing words, in the case of Quintilian 10.1.13 – on the basis of some other word and, in this way, 'borrowing' from that other word.)

Comment: It is interesting if the Romans used the same word for borrowing and deriving in this context. Perhaps that distinction should be explored in another question...

Answer (score 2):

The primary meaning of 'borrow' in English is to use something with the intention of returning it after use, and the verb is thus the correlative of 'lend'. In a separate idiom, the word is used entirely properly, but  to mean something like 'convert' or 'appropriate'.

That doesn't mean that there is no single Latin word that is exactly suitable for both cases. The verb *mutuor*, indeed, has the exact sense of the English, either as the correlative of 'lend', or simply to 'adopt', or 'take for one's own use' etc.