# Did the Romans distinguish derivation and loan?

Tags: classical-latin, grammar-choice, passage-request

I learned from [this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5537/79) that the Romans used the same verb *mutuari* both for loaning words from Greek and deriving new words within Latin.
Are there any examples in classical literature that make a distinction between derivation and loan?
Or were they considered the same thing?
After all, they are both instances of repurposing old words; the difference is only in the source of the material.

It is possible that the extant evidence is insufficient, and that is indeed one possible answer.
If there are other verbs the Romans used for borrowing words from other languages, please consider leaving an answer to the linked question whether you answer this one or not.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of my reply to the other question here. 'Loan word' is an English expression for a word taken from another language. Strictly, a _loan_ is something _lent_ in expectation of its return and the term _loan word_, is widely accepted, but used inaccurately — just as it is 'inaccurate' to 'borrow' a word that you can't give back!