# "axiology" in Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, word-request, philosophy-terms

> Axiology (from Greek ἀξία, axia: "value, worth"; and -λογία, -logia: "study of") is the philosophical study of value.

It is a branch of philosophy that includes politics (*Scientia civilis*), ethics (*Scientia moralis*), aesthetics, etc.

What would be a good Latin translation of it? Preferably of the form *Scientia + -lis*. I know that I could latinize axiology to axiologia but I would rater not use a loan word.

Answer (score 3):

I gather axiology is about the things people value rather than value in the economic sense, so *pretium* is inappropriate, and while *valor* is presumably nearer the mark, it is not attested Classically—though neither are the terms *scientia civilis* and *scientia moralis*, of course.
Still, I would go with a derivative of [*aestimo*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=aestimo) (whence also English *esteem*), which covers both monetary and other kinds of value. The obvious noun [*aestimatio*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0060:entry=aestimatio) is also usually concerned with monetary value in the corpus because it became a term of art in Roman law, but I feel it's still usable and intuitively understandable in that a branch of philosophy that *is* concerned with monetary value would itself much more likely go with *pretium* instead. There is no corresponding adjective in *-alis* the way there is for *civis*/*civilis* and *mos*/*moralis*; if there were, it would be **aestimationalis*, which is transparent but not attested.

*Scientia* is demonstrably fine, so no reason to change that.

So, my suggestion: **scientia aestimātiōnum**, the science of valuations. Or, if you don't mind neologisms: **scientia aestimātiōnālis**.

Comment: That's a great answer thank you! Are you sure scientia civilis is not attested?

Comment: @Victor As far as I know the term was coined by Thomas Hobbes.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any exact match for English's *-ology* suffix, but, taking a hint from Joonas's *studium sapientiae* for *philosophia* (from [this link](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4215/what-is-philosophy-in-latin)) I'd guess *studium valorum* or *studium pretiorum* would work.

*Studium*, according to my dictionary (Traupman), means eagerness, enthusiasm, keenness, or study. It's not an exact match for *-ology*, but there is considerable overlap. In my experience, -ologists usually are quite keen on their field.

There are other options for *studium*, of course. There is *disciplina*, which perhaps better captures the organized methodology or study of a field. You mentioned *scientia*, which could also work, especially if by "science" you mean mainly a body of knowlege. If you mean the craft or skill of the field, you could go with *calliditas pretiorum*. If you are talking about the profession, you could use *artificium pretiorum*, the "craftmanship of values".

Like with *studium* none of these is an exact match for *axiologia*, but if you want to avoid Greek roots you'll have to compromise, or resort to circumlocutions.

If by values you are talking about morals and not economics, then you will probably want to replace *pretiorum* with *morum*, *finium* or *valorum* in the examples above. Both *mores* and *finis* have specialized meaning in philosophical Latin, and *valor* may as well.

Comment: *Studium* can mean the *act* of studying in some contexts, but not a *field* of study. It's in the semantic field of expending effort towards something, English "study" is now a false friend.