# ¿Cómo se dice "valor" de ser apreciado en alguna manera por algún observador?

Tags: classical-latin, noun

(English version below.)

Quiero escribir en latín un pequeño ensayo sobre los diferentes tipos del valor que uno le da a las cosas, pero mi diccionario español-latín me esta dando solamente para precio económico pretium (el cual es el mas cercano bajo el paradigma del valor subjetivo de los bienes), algo sobre legalidad aestimatio y valentía fortitudo (esto no debería estar aquí), virtus [ánimo, valentía, espiritual], y ninguna me convence.

Debo aclarar que necesito que las siguientes frases tengan sentido:

1. El valor de los frutos de una actividad.
2. El valor de una cosa es el valor que piensas que tiene.
3. El valor de tu vida es el valor que tu piensas tiene.

## Importante: Todo respuesta debe de incluir las anteriores frases ejemplo con la palabra propuesta.

Espero que sea posible escribir los siguientes ejemplos de frase usando la palabra propuesta para valor aunque no tiene que ser para nada literal:

1. Este producto es muy valioso
2. Este producto no tiene valor

---

How do you say in Latin "value" of being appreciated in some way by some observer?

I want to write a small essay in Latin about the different types of value that one gives to things, but my Spanish-Latin dictionary is only giving me for economic price *pretium* (which is the closest under the paradigm of the subjective value of goods), something about legality *aestimatio* and valor *fortitudo* (this shouldn't be here), *virtus* [courage, bravery, spiritual], and none of them convince me.

I must clarify that I need the following phrases to make sense:

1. The value of the fruits of a work.
2. The value of a thing is the value what you think it has.
3. The value of your life is the value that you think it has.

## Important: Every answer must include the example sentences up with the proposed word.

I expect the following example phrases to be able to be written to the written using the proposed word for value, but this examples phrases not are needed to be literal.

1. This product is very valuable
2. This product has no value

Comment: Relacionado: https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/19482/14272

Comment: I think that I will chosse either the latin aestimatio or the greek import axia.

Answer (score 1):

A not-so-bad alternative could be late Latin **[valor/-oris](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dvalor)**, from which Spanish *valor* comes from, derived from the verb **[valeo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dvaleo)**, meaning *strength, power, worth, ability, efficacy, value*, etc.

**Update:** In turn, the question you link in the comments seems to offer a pretty good alternative: the verb **[æstimo](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Daestimo)**, (*to determine the value of, estimate, value, rate, appraise*,) and its derived noun **[æstimatio](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Daestimatio)**

Comment: Does it mean "value" like "I value you"? At least, that's how I'm interpreting the question.

Comment: @cmw I value you, I value thiat thing, I don't see aestetic value in this paint, and every imaginable use of value.

Comment: @Dolphínus I didn't realize you also wanted a verb. BTW, the question you link seems to suggest a better option: **æestimatio/-onis**, and the verb **æstimo** fit most of the meaning you want to convey, if I get it right.

Comment: @Rafael I think that neither I realized that I wanted a verb.

Comment: Just how I would write, that has no value, and it has a lot of value with eastimatio?

Comment: @Dolphínus I think you might need more than one word, in that case. Adjectives like [pretiosus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpretiosus) and [nequam](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dnequam) also have some figurative value, and keep continuity with the general idea

Comment: @Dolphínus BTW, I appraise your curiosity, but the idea of StackExchange is to serve as a knowledge base for future visitors. This suggests that you either edit the question into having more detail, or add a separate question for further inquiries, rather than the intuitive way of commenting those in. SE is not like your regular forum. (I'm struggling not to write to you in Spanish, for the same reason.)

Answer (score -1):

Here are several words to consider:

*habitus* - which can mean the quality of something or the character of a man

*fructus* - the "fruit" of something is an indication of its value. For example:

*...ceterarum rerum quarum **fructum** utilitate metimur* ("... of other things whose **value** we rate by their utility") -- Cicero

*pretium* - the word for price is often used to allegorically mean the value or worth of something. *aestimatio* has a similar force. For example:

*Abstrahunt a recto divitiae, honores, potentia et cetera, quae opinione nostra cara sunt, pretio suo vilia.* ("We are deflected from the right course by riches, titles, power, and everything which is valuable in our opinion but worthless when rated at its real value.") -- Seneca

*meritum* - is the merit of something, what it deserves and can mean its value, mostly in poetic or post-classical contexts. For example:

*Sacra recognosces annalibus eruta priscis, et quo sit merito quaeque notata dies.* ("You shall learn of holy rites unearthed from the ancients, and learn of how every day has its particular worth.") -- Ovid, *Fasti*

Comment: (1) I don't think that habits would make a great use of value in the latin translation of Human Action by Mises.
(2) The circulality of Fructus fructús actús (valuation of the gains of the activiy) does scare me away of fructus. 
(3) Pretium huius réí est quod putás pretium eius réí esse also scares me away from pretium, or in general its money implications.
(4) Meritum vitae tuae est quod pútas vita tua habere, scare me away of meritum.

Comment: Do you think that a greek word import could work?